# Passing a jquery array into a hidden form field in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

On my page I got a bunch of photo items which I can select/deselect with checkboxes:

```
<div id="image-item">
    <img src="image_on_server.jpg">
    <input name="images-checkbox" id="images-checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

The checkbox is created in rails with a `check_box_tag`.

This is the AJAX form on the same page where I can set a tag for all the selected photos at once:

```
=form_tag(batch_tagging_users_album_photos_path(@album), method: 'post', remote: true, id: 'tagging-form') do 
  .field                                                                                                      
    = text_field_tag :tag                                                                                     
    = hidden_field_tag 'checkboxes[]'                                                                           
    = button_tag 'Submit Tag', type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-default'#, id: 'batch-tagging'
```

From all I know, the square brackets signal Rails that the field input will be an array.

This little snippet of jquery makes sure that the hidden input field `checkboxes[]` will grab the array of selected items and send it to my controller action `batch_tagging`.

```
   $('form#tagging-form').on('submit', function() {     
    $('input[name="checkboxes[]"]').val(checkboxes)    
  });
```

The batch_tagging action inside my photos_controller:

```
 def batch_tagging                                                                
   @checked_items = @album.photos.where(id: params[:checkboxes])                                                                    

   respond_to do |format|                                                         
     if Photo.update_tags(@checked_items, tag)                                    
       format.js                                                                  
       flash[:notice] = 'Photos successfully tagged'                              
     else                                                                         
       format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }  
     end                                                                          
   end                                                                            
 end
```

So far, so good... @checked_items receives the data but unfortunately as a single string. In order to process all of the items (not just the first one) I need to set @checked_items as an array of strings.

So what I get now as parameters:

```
  Processing by Users::PhotosController#batch_tagging as JS                                                         
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "tag"=>"awesome_tag", "checkboxes"=>["421,422"], "button"=>"", "album_id"=>"some_friendly-id"}
```

What I need:

```
  Processing by Users::PhotosController#batch_tagging as JS                                                         
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "tag"=>"awesome_tag", "checkboxes"=>["421","422"], "button"=>"", "album_id"=>"some_friendly-id"}
```

Of course, I could take the string on controller level, break it up and be done with it, but it seems cleaner to send an array of strings via the form.

What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you show the other form with photo checkboxes?

Comment: @Pablo, I added that piece of code you requested.